# Socket Programming from multiple clients to server and server to multiple clients in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am able to send text files from multiple clients to the server but unable to send a text file from server to multiple clients at once. I anyone can modify the code for the same it will we really helpful. The question is to send text file from one server to multiple clients and multiple clients to server but the clients can't communicate with each other.

This is the client code.

client.py

```
import socket

#IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 4456
ADDR = (IP, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
SIZE = 1024

def main():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)

    while True:
        data = client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        cmd, msg = data.split("@")

        if cmd == "DISCONNECTED":
            print(f"[SERVER]: {msg}")
            break
        elif cmd == "OK":
            print(f"{msg}")

        data = input("> ")
        data = data.split(" ")
        cmd = data[0]

        if cmd == "HELP":
            client.send(cmd.encode(FORMAT))
        elif cmd == "LOGOUT":
            client.send(cmd.encode(FORMAT))
            break
        elif cmd == "LIST":
            client.send(cmd.encode(FORMAT))
        elif cmd == "DELETE":
            client.send(f"{cmd}@{data[1]}".encode(FORMAT))
        elif cmd == "UPLOAD":
            path = data[1]

            with open(f"{path}", "r") as f:
                text = f.read()

            filename = path.split("/")[-1]
            send_data = f"{cmd}@{filename}@{text}"
            client.send(send_data.encode(FORMAT))

    print("Disconnected from the server.")
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the server code.

server.py

```
import os
import socket
import threading

#IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 4456
ADDR = (IP, PORT)
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"
SERVER_DATA_PATH = "server_data"

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    conn.send("OK@Welcome to the File Server.".encode(FORMAT))

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        data = data.split("@")
        cmd = data[0]

        if cmd == "LIST":
            files = os.listdir(SERVER_DATA_PATH)
            send_data = "OK@"

            if len(files) == 0:
                send_data += "The server directory is empty"
            else:
                send_data += "\n".join(f for f in files)
            conn.send(send_data.encode(FORMAT))

        elif cmd == "UPLOAD":
            name, text = data[1], data[2]
            filepath = os.path.join(SERVER_DATA_PATH, name)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(text)

            send_data = "OK@File uploaded successfully."
            conn.send(send_data.encode(FORMAT))

        elif cmd == "DELETE":
            files = os.listdir(SERVER_DATA_PATH)
            send_data = "OK@"
            filename = data[1]

            if len(files) == 0:
                send_data += "The server directory is empty"
            else:
                if filename in files:
                    os.system(f"rm {SERVER_DATA_PATH}/{filename}")
                    send_data += "File deleted successfully."
                else:
                    send_data += "File not found."

            conn.send(send_data.encode(FORMAT))

        elif cmd == "LOGOUT":
            break
        elif cmd == "HELP":
            data = "OK@"
            data += "LIST: List all the files from the server.\n"
            data += "UPLOAD <path>: Upload a file to the server.\n"
            data += "DELETE <filename>: Delete a file from the server.\n"
            data += "LOGOUT: Disconnect from the server.\n"
            data += "HELP: List all the commands."

            conn.send(data.encode(FORMAT))

    print(f"[DISCONNECTED] {addr} disconnected")
    conn.close()

def main():
    print("[STARTING] Server is starting")
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(ADDR)
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {IP}:{PORT}.")

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: TCP is not a message-based protocol. One send does not correspond to one receive. Any code that assumes that is broken. Check your return values. Design a protocol to ensure you receive all the bytes of your message.